# final variable not const enough for switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
public class Main {

    static final String fu = Week.class.getName();

    public static void main(String[] arg0){

        String h = "dummy";
        switch (h) {
*        case fu:
            System.out.println(8);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now Eclipse complains at * that `case expressions must be constant expressions`. But I made `fu` as constant as I know to do! Why is this not enough, what can I do (other than if-else)?

Comment: There is a *fundamental difference* between a *constant* and a *static data member* declared `final`. The compiler doesn't deal in grey areas of semantic meaning; it deals in hard cold categories.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this not enough

Because it's not a compile-time constant by the rules of [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

> Why is this not enough, what can I do (other than if-else)?

Nothing, basically - unless you use a string literal, which would obviously not be very pleasant.

Comment: In other words, you have to specify the content of your string. You can't initialize it dynamically, since it isn't compile-time constant, as specified in the rules mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue seems like compiler expects a value at compile time so as to make the your string variable as **constant**.
In your case class name is coming @ runtime not at compile time so compiler will not consider that as a **constant**
For a variable to be constant 

- **INITIALIZED WITH CONSTANT EXPRESSION ONLY**

- **should be declare as final**

-**primitive or String**

 - **initialize while declaration**

So you **void** the 1st condition. Just for reference check the following program-

Here  **case x**  will give error as it is coming @ runtime from class. But if set it to some constant like 20 it will run fine.

```
  package com;

    public class Main {

    static final int x = Week.getx();

    public static void main(String[] arg0){

        int i = 10;
        switch (i)
        {
        case x : System.out.println("Hello"); break;

        case 12 : System.out.println("Bye"); break;

        }

            }
}
```

package com;

```
public class Week {

public static int  getx()
{
    return 10;
}
}
```

Tell if you need more explanation!